# Find arrays in db linked with a user through routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes

I have a route which is gathering the arrays from my json db.

I want to only get the arrays where the user_id is matching.

Here is my code now:

```
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
Bet.find()
    .then(bets => res.json(bets))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

With this code I'm retrieving all results in the json.

I've tried `Bet.find({ user_id: req.body.user_id })` but it doesn't return anything. user_id is an object in the json.

Here is something what I want, but this code isn't working aswell with me:
[Github - mern plaid](https://github.com/rishipr/mern-plaid/blob/master/routes/api/plaid.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by doing:

```
router.route("/:id").get((req, res) => {
Bet.find({ user_id: req.params.id })
    .then(bets => res.json(bets))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the findByID method and see if this resolved the issue.

```
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {

let id = req.body.user_id ;
Bet.findById(id, function (err, bets ) {
    res.json(bets );
});
```

})

Comment: This returns null, maybe my req.body.user_id is empty?